# Any electronic versions of philosophical texts structured like biblehub?

Tags: reference-request

[Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/) is absolutely awesome. It contains any possible tools a scholar could dream of.

I wonder if anybody did similar work with any philosophical texts? I personally would greatly benefit from a similar rendering of Plato's Parmenides, but obviously I would warmly welcome similar treatment of any other sources.

I would be deeply grateful for links to any such kind of resources, either for classical or contemporary philosophical texts.

Comment: I'm sure other people will have some good suggestions, but as a first baseline (which others might like to propose improvements on), might I suggest Project Gutenberg's philosophy eBook collection? https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/bookshelf/57

Comment: So far as I am aware there is no single site, however, there are ambitious projects ongoing. For ancient Greek and Roman texts,  Perseus is a fabulous enterprise. For example, spend some time and find out the facilities at http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0173%3Atext%3DParm.%3Asection%3D126a.

Comment: @PaulRoss Project Gutenberg is certainly a valuable source, but I meant more some kind of structured data, using advantages of hypertext in an essential way.

Comment: @TankutBeygu I should certainly mention Perseus, thanks! For example, it gives possibility to translate words on the spot. Do you know if it can provide search for parallel places or things like that? In general, I think an answer describing at least some of the possibilities that Perseus provides would be very useful.

Comment: *Deus Magnus Est* ~ *Nomen nescio*.